# Check if variable is set in filter

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, functions, filters

Thanks to your suggestions, I enabled wp_debug and discovered flaws with my plugin. I have a filter for sorting posts by votes. I use it when the `sort` URL parameter is on.

`add_filter( 'posts_where', 'votes', 10, 2 );`

I used to get `Undefined index: sort` so I modified my function to first check if the variable is set.

```
function votes( $where, $query )
{
  $sort = array_key_exists('sort', $query->query_vars) ? $_GET['sort'] : null;
  if ( isset($sort) ) {         
       $where .= " AND $sort >= votes";               
  }
  return $where;
}
```

This works fine but I'm not confident if it's correct. I'm wondering if there's a better method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you have named `$query` is actually the WP_Query instance having filters applied to it.

You can simply call its function `get` to retrieve query vars.

For example:

```
function votes( $where, $query )
{
    $sort = $query->get('sort');
    if (!empty($sort)
        $where .= " AND $sort >= votes";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That must be the best method :) I get no more `Undefined index` while the code is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

If you check for `$query->query_vars` first but then use `$_GET['sort']` later on, you have just checked or used the wrong variable. I think this just happened when you edited the script.

you probably wanted to write this:

```
 $sort = array_key_exists('sort', $query->query_vars) ? $query->query_vars['sort'] : null;
```